# deleting a subclass, deletes the parent as well

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a situation where I'm using a table per subclass for association. The mappings are fine until I try and delete a record from the subclass table. The delete cause's not only the subclass to be deleted, but also the parent. I can understand this feature may be by design, but is there anyway to just delete the subclass?

Here's my sample code.

```
public class ParentClassMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentClassMap ()
    {
        Table("tblParent");
        Id(x => x.ParentId).Column("ParentId").GeneratedBy.Identity()
        ... other properties
    }
}

public class ChildClassMap : SubClassMap<Child>
{
    public ChildClassMap()
    {
        Table("tblChild");
        KeyColumn("ParentId");
        ... other properties
    }
}
```

Now when I query for a record, everything seems fine

```
Child child = session.CreateCriteria<Parent>().Add(Restrictions.Eq("ParentId", 1)).UniqueResult<Parent>();
```

But when I delete the child, the sql executed includes updates to all tables that reference either Parent or Child, then the deletion of Child then Parent.

```
session.Delete(child);
```

I only want to delete the Child Object, is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Think about it in OOP terms: if you have an object of the class `Dog` that inherits from `Animal`, does it makes sense to "delete the dog, but leave the animal"?

Which brings me to the next point: if you can delete "part" of an object, then you should **not** be using a subclass, but an association (probably one-to-one or many-to-one)

Comment: Thanks Diego, I kinda knew that was the case, I was just hoping I wasn't right.